# Trying to Delete a Rectangle Hitbox from a Game Made In JavaFX, But It's Not Working

Tags: java, javafx

I'm quite new to Java Programming and I am currently trying to build a game. So far, I am able to switch between levels, however, the hitboxes from the previous level would still exist in the pane, just not drawn. The code for that section of the game is here :

```
private void switchLevel(int l) {
    switch (l) {
    case 1:
        this.level = new Level1();
        break;
    case 2: 
        this.level = new Level2();
        this.getChildren().clear();
        break;
}

    hitBoxes.clear();
    mobs.clear();
    this.getChildren().addAll(hitBoxes);
    background.setImage(level.getImage());  // get the background image
    hitBoxes.addAll(level.getWalls());      // get all the wall hitboxes
    enemyCount = level.getEnemyCount();     // get the enemy count from the level
    chestCount = level.treasureCount();     // get the treasure count from the level
    this.getChildren().add(background);     // add the lvlMap imageview to scene
    this.getChildren().addAll(hitBoxes);    // add all the hitboxes for the walls to the scene
    this.initTreasure(chestCount);          // add the treasure chests for the level
    this.initMobs(enemyCount);              // initialize our mobs
```

As you can see in the code above, I have tried deleting the hitboxes that were added to the first level by clearing the pane with this line of code: `this.getChildren().clear();`

When the level switches, the hitboxes for level 2 do get added, but the hitboxes from the first level still persist except they are invisible. Does clearing the pane remove the actual rectangle objects or does it just make them not be drawn in the pane? If it is the latter, how would I go about actually removing the rectangle objects from the pane?

Comment: Hello @NoxAquilam, could you please give us more code? I don't see where are you calling the `switchLevel` method.

Comment: what's needed is a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Also what's this supposed to achieve (besides clearing one of the lists):` hitBoxes.clear(); ... this.getChildren().addAll(hitBoxes);` Adding everything in an empty list does not change the list.

Comment: Also if you feel the need to delete [an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58946839/javafx-game-not-changing-levels-properly) just to ask it again in a new post, be sure to listen to the advice in the comments. You still haven't produced a [mcve] and until you do I'm pretty sure the chances of getting an useful answer are close to 0.